# Can I batch import attribute tables into existing excel spreadsheets

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, table, batch, excel

I am using arcGIS 10.2 and I need to import the attribute tables of 100 layers into existing excel spreadsheets which will make graphs based on the values in the attribute tables.

Doing this manually is as simple as copying and pasting the attribute tables into the excel spreadsheets. However, this is quite tedious.

Is there a way that I can automatically insert these tables into the right sections of the excel spreadsheets?

Comment: This would probably be simpler done as an Excel macro (after you've exported the attribute tables to txt or csv). Alternatively, you could put together a Python script to collate all the attribute tables into one csv, and then import THAT into Excel (without macros).

Comment: Also you can write it in R, just like in Python.

Comment: You can't use R if the data is in a geodatabase. Not sure if that's the case here, though.

Answer (score 2):

The following model will go through a folder of shapefiles and export each one into an Excel file. It is using inline substitution to give each xls document a unique name (based upon the input FeatureClass).

There are no out of the box tools that I am aware of that will export multiple tables into a single *existing* workbook. ArcGIS can only access an Excel Workbook in a read-only mode.

[image: Model]

You will need to write some custom code as @Erica suggested if you want all tables in a single workbook as separate sheets.